# Developing a more efficient array and for loop script in Python

Tags: python, list, parsing, dictionary

I'm working in python to iterate through some arrays and then fill cells in rows after each array data point has been written from the array into excel.

Currently, my script works fine, but it looks terrible and am wondering a more efficient way I could code this. Should I put all the lists into an ordered dictionary? I'm mainly looking to get rid of the crazy amount of for loops.

## Array Definitions

```
delay_time_data             = []
step_size_data              = [1,1,1,1,1]
first_uncorrectable_data    = []
second_uncorrectable_data   = []
erasure_decode_data         = []
ecc_hibit_data              = []
bits_corrected_data         = []
bits_read_data              = []
avg_rber_data               = []
avg_rber_ed_data            = []
ed_success_data             = []
```

## Loops

```
#Fill in the logged data from the test ouput under each delay_time column
    for each_item in step_size_data:
        current_cell_iteration = '%s%d'%(xlsx_cols[current_letter], column_iterator) #STARTING AT CURRENT CELL OF 
        overall_stats_sheet[current_cell_iteration] = each_item
        current_letter+=1

    current_letter      = 1
    column_iterator     +=1

    for each_item in first_uncorrectable_data:
        current_cell_iteration = '%s%d'%(xlsx_cols[current_letter], column_iterator) #STARTING AT CURRENT CELL OF 
        overall_stats_sheet[current_cell_iteration] = each_item
        current_letter+=1

    current_letter      = 1
    column_iterator     +=1

    for each_item in second_uncorrectable_data:
        current_cell_iteration = '%s%d'%(xlsx_cols[current_letter], column_iterator) #STARTING AT CURRENT CELL OF 
        overall_stats_sheet[current_cell_iteration] = each_item
        current_letter+=1

    current_letter      = 1
    column_iterator     +=1

    for each_item in erasure_decode_data:
        current_cell_iteration = '%s%d'%(xlsx_cols[current_letter], column_iterator) #STARTING AT CURRENT CELL OF 
        overall_stats_sheet[current_cell_iteration] = each_item
        current_letter+=1

    current_letter      = 1
    column_iterator     +=1

    for each_item in ecc_hibit_data:
        current_cell_iteration = '%s%d'%(xlsx_cols[current_letter], column_iterator) #STARTING AT CURRENT CELL OF 
        overall_stats_sheet[current_cell_iteration] = each_item
        current_letter+=1

    current_letter      = 1
    column_iterator     +=1

    for each_item in bits_corrected_data:
        current_cell_iteration = '%s%d'%(xlsx_cols[current_letter], column_iterator) #STARTING AT CURRENT CELL OF 
        overall_stats_sheet[current_cell_iteration] = each_item
        current_letter+=1

    current_letter      = 1
    column_iterator     +=1

    for each_item in bits_read_data:
        current_cell_iteration = '%s%d'%(xlsx_cols[current_letter], column_iterator) #STARTING AT CURRENT CELL OF 
        overall_stats_sheet[current_cell_iteration] = each_item
        current_letter+=1

    current_letter      = 1
    column_iterator     +=1

    for each_item in avg_rber_data:
        current_cell_iteration = '%s%d'%(xlsx_cols[current_letter], column_iterator) #STARTING AT CURRENT CELL OF 
        overall_stats_sheet[current_cell_iteration] = each_item
        current_letter+=1

    current_letter      = 1
    column_iterator     +=1

    for each_item in avg_rber_ed_data:
        current_cell_iteration = '%s%d'%(xlsx_cols[current_letter], column_iterator) #STARTING AT CURRENT CELL OF 
        overall_stats_sheet[current_cell_iteration] = each_item
        current_letter+=1
```

Comment: Make a dict of the lists, iterate through it with a for loop and then nest the for loop you are currently using.

Comment: I don't think "efficient" is the correct word here. You want to improve readability, not performance, correct?

Comment: Matt: More or less, that is what I am looking for. Readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments, "Make a dict of the lists, iterate through it with a for loop and then nest the for loop you are currently using."

```
data = {
    'delay_time': [],
    'step_size': [1,1,1,1,1],
    'first_uncorrectable': [],
    'second_uncorrectable': [],
    'erasure_decode': [],
    'ecc_hibit': [],
    'bits_corrected': [],
    'bits_read': [],
    'avg_rber': [],
    'avg_rber_ed': [],
    'ed_success': []
}

for data_set in data:
    for each_item in data[data_set]:
        current_cell_iteration = '%s%d'%(xlsx_cols[current_letter], column_iterator) #STARTING AT CURRENT CELL OF
        overall_stats_sheet[current_cell_iteration] = each_item
        current_letter += 1
    current_letter = 1
    column_iterator += 1
```

Hope this helps!